# Force applied by a fluid in upward direction during its motion

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, flow

If a fluid flows in a horizontal pipe it apply a force due to its weight in downward direction but why fluid apply force normally in upward direction on pipe

Comment: Can you specify your question more , like is it moving in a horizontal pipe or in a vertical pipe and which force are you talking about is it  fluid's normal force ?  what is significance moving fluid to normal forces and weight (it doesnt change it)